# Binary search and adversary argument for a sorted nxn matrix

Tags: python, binary-search-tree

M is nXn integer matrix in which the keys in each row are in increasing order (reading left to right) and the keys in each column are in increasing order (reading top to bottom). Consider the problem of finding the position of an integer x in M , or determining that x is not there. Find an efficient algorithm to solve the problem. Provide an adversary argument to state the lower bound for
this problem. Explain about the optimality of your algorithm.
For this i created a python code that has runs binary search with complexity O(logn+logm), but how can I state the adversary argument and find its complexity to know if it is optimal or not?

The code is the following:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z1Hz0.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FrYD6.png)

Comment: Please don't post code as an image. Type the code.